# PHPStorm: Auto generate the inheritdoc documentation when implementing methods of an abstract parent class

Tags: phpstorm

Been using PHPStorm and whenever I implement the abstract method of a parent class to some subclass I run the `Implement Methods` command in which it auto-generates the function blocks and its doc blocks.

It annoys me that I still need to manually modify the doc blocks to `{@inheritdoc}`.

My question now, Is there a way to configure PHPStorm to generate `{@inheritdoc}` doc block when implementing methods instead of it generating the original doc block?

Comment: Unfortunately not -- ATM it's not configurable.

Comment: Oh. hope they can put it in one of their updates. @LazyOne

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16547 indicates that it's been implemented, but https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27869 says it hasn't, so I don't know what to think. It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've been having the same problem.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me No not yet. I'll just wait for Jetbrains for updates I guess. hehe

Answer (score 6):

1. In the menu go to `Code > Generate > Implement method` (Ctrl+I)
2. Check 'Add PHPDoc'
3. Select 'With @inheritDoc tag'

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16547

Comment: Not ideal, but still better than the autofix. +1